# Streaming a tarball after stripping components

Tags: bash, tar

I have a tarball with the following structure:

```
/a/b/c/file1.txt
/a/b/c/file2.txt
/a/b/c/file3.txt
/a/b/c/file4.txt
```

I want to stream the tarball to another software STDIN but I would like to apply first `--strip-components=2` so that the software would see a tarball with a structure like:

```
/c/file1.txt
/c/file2.txt
/c/file3.txt
/c/file4.txt
```

If I didn't need to strip the path I would just do:

`cat my_tarball.tar | other_software`

How can this be achieved without creating another tarball in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple perl script that reads a tar file, strips N leading components (Default 2) from filenames in it, and writes the modified archive to standard output:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Archive::Tar;
use Getopt::Long;

# Usage: rewrite.pl [--strip-components=N] [tarfile]
# If no filename given, reads from standard input.
# Can read gzip compressed tar files given a filename,
# but /not/ if reading from stdin.
# Always writes an uncompressed archive.

my $level = 2;
GetOptions("strip-components=i" => \$level)
  or die "Error in command line arguments.\n";

my $tar = Archive::Tar->new(@ARGV ? $ARGV[0] : \*STDIN);
for my $file ($tar->get_files) {
  my @components = split "/", $file->full_path;
  $file->rename(join("/", @components[$level..$#components]));
}
$tar->write(\*STDOUT);
```

Example:

```
$ tar tf foo.tar
a/b/c/x.txt
a/b/c/y.txt
a/b/c/z.txt
$ perl rewrite.pl foo.tar | tar tf -
c/x.txt
c/y.txt
c/z.txt
```